# How to wrap an element around a character using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to wrap a span around some characters in an element.

For example:

    `<div>Some random string</div>;`

And then if javascript randomly pick the "m" in "random" and the "r" in string.  I want it to become this:

    `<div>Some rando<span>m</span> st<span>r</span>ing</div>`

How would I do that without jQuery's replace?

The native replace doesn't change the original string and simply overwriting the original string with the modified string removes other stylings to the element.  I've also investigated with insertNode but with no avail.

Comment: Take a look at http://letteringjs.com/.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but maybe something like: http://jsfiddle.net/7fhJw/ - it's kind of confusing, because you need to just get the text, but you have to set the HTML content. It obviously gets complicated when the specific element has children elements, as `.text()` only returns their inner text

Comment: This demonstrates a [replace with pseudo-markup awareness](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/JaN75/49/). The complexity derives from selecting a *word* (as opposed to a *letter*) that may have multiple overlapping elements; for instance, in the demo, try typing `Yesterday` and you'll notice it stops at `Yester` then goes away. That's what I would guess @Blender means when he suggests using a library instead of trying to do it yourself.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Your demo kinda breaks for the input "e".

Comment: @Blender - Yes, yes. It does.

Answer (score 0):

Does this helps :

I generated `2 random numbers` and then wrapped them with span and got the result you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gkkbb/2/

Answer (score 0):

if you only *add* span tags inside the innerHTML, all styling should remain (unless you have subelement you care about).

Assuming that:

- there is no sub-elements in your div
- the text content itself is html-safe
- You have a way to find the indexes of the characters you want wrapped

(all assumptions seem true in your example)

You could transform the original string and reinject it with .html()

Since I don't know *how* you pick the indexes you care about, I leave that to you, but, again within stated assumption, you could do this:

```
var my_div = $('some_selector_goes_here');
var original = my_div.text();

var indexes = find_the_indexes(original);

var updated = '', cur_idx = 0;
for (var idx=0; idx<indexes.length; idx++)
{
    var index = indexes[idx];
    updated += original.substr(cur_idx, index);
    updated += '<span>' + original.charAt(index) + '</span>';
    cur_idx = index + 1;
}
updated += original.substr(cur_idx);

my_div.html(updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example .. Edit as you need ..

```
<div id='div'>Some random string</div>


<script>
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var OurString = div.innerHTML.split(' '); // array containing words of div
var StringToFind = 'random',CharToFind = 'm';
var span = document.createElement('span');
div.innerHTML = '';
for(var i=0;i<OurString.length;i++)
{
if(StringToFind == OurString[i])
{
div.innerHTML += OurString[i].substring(0,OurString[i].indexOf(CharToFind));
div.appendChild(span);
span.innerHTML = CharToFind;
div.innerHTML += OurString[i].substring(OurString[i].indexOf(CharToFind) + 1,OurString[i].length);
}
else
div.innerHTML += OurString[i];
div.innerHTML = ' ';
}
</script>
```